# parse meta header for URL address in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to get meta data for a URL address and I'm using this code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cuMAeGOCng"]];
    [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.42"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
    }];
    [task resume];
```

is this right ? 
Also the returned data is encoded and can't figure how to decode it! any clues ?

Thanks

Comment: It's right convert NSData to NSString
        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

Comment: @MohammadAlavi Yes, the data now is readable but the fetched information is about the whole site !

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cuMAeGOCng"]];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.42"
forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

 NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)
                          {

   NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);


                          }];
  [task resume];
```